# EasyAdminBundle 3:collection field with entity

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5, easyadmin

I have two classes:

```php
class Product {
     /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity=Keyword::class, mappedBy="product")
     */
    private $keywords;
}

class Keyword {
     /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity=Product::class, inversedBy="keywords")
     */
    private $product;
}
```

In my CRUD controller of Product I defined:

```php
public function configureFields(string $pageName): iterable
{
     yield CollectionField::new('keywords');
}
```

and it properly shows all the keywords but when I try to save it I get an error:

> Expected argument of type "App\Entity\Keyword", "string" given at property path "keywords".

Is there a possibility to show such a connection as a Collection? It would be MUCH easier to manage keywords that way.

Answer (score 1):

You should create CRUD controller for Keyword entity and specify fields for records creation/editing.

After, you can use CollectionField in Product CRUD controller as below:

```
yield CollectionField::new('keywords')->useEntryCrudForm(KeywordsCrudController::class);
```

Comment: Note: `useEntryCrudForm` is from EA 4 with symfony 6.1, so it's not available in EA 3.

Answer (score -3):

You need to use

```
yield AssociationField::new('keywords');
```

instead of

```
yield CollectionField::new('keywords');
```